# Regex RE2: Extract text inside brackets at the end of a string including brackets and only the last set if more than one

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I'm using Google Sheets, which uses RE2 syntax.  All my data has brackets at the end of the string with numbers and sometimes other characters also.  Some rows have more than one set of brackets with something in there.  I only want to remove the last set of brackets and the content between

If I have:
This is a bit random (2019)(861.01)

Then I want to return:
This is a bit random (2019)

and if I have:
This is a bit random (861.01)

I want to return:
This is a bit random

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about `=TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^(.*)\("))`

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*$","")
```

Comment: Thank you Rocky.  That is precisely what I was after!

Comment: There is a space being left at the end of the resulting text. I see that \s is whitespace, but I can't see where to put this in the formula provided?  I prefer to not use the trim function as a space may be required by the data I have - so removing one whitespace character, if there is one, is preferred in the regex function.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use `TRIM` try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*$", ), " $", ))
```

[image]